# API Service calls between Lotus Domino and React js

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, lotus-domino

The application's front end has been developed in React js. That needs to be integrated with Lotus Domino as  backend. I have been asked to write API service calls (I am new to this) between the two, so that to prepare CRUD operations dynamically. Like creating a new document or updating an existing document dynamically using API calls. The Node and the Domino server are installed on the same Server. And we are not using http requests for this.

Thanks in advance for  your help.

Comment: Why are you not using http requests?

Comment: do you have api's for lotus-domino etc. Plz add more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AppDev Pack and the domino-db module for node.js:
https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/homepage.html

C3UG (Cross Canada Collaboration User Group) has created a free course to learn how to use the AppDev Pack:
http://www.c3ug.ca/c3ug-blog/2020/6/30/announcement-learning-the-domino-appdev-pack-a-free-course-from-c3ug

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. You mention Domino as backend - on the other hand you mention a node server. In most cases where node is involved the backend is developed on top of node.
If you want to develop the backend on node and use Domino as database then go with the domino-db module. If the backend should be developed on Domino you have (at least) three options:

1. Web agent(s) that handle(s) client requests. This is quite low level but you could employ Java libs to assist you. This approach integrates with Dominos http task.
2. A Java servlet that handles requests. Integrates with http tasks, too. But does not do user authentication for you.
3. An AddIn task or standalone Java program. This is the most flexible solution but also the most extensive. And it does not integrate with http task